# memmem on Windows

Tags: c, windows

I was recently porting an application that uses `memmem` from Linux to Windows.
While `memmem` is available as a library function on Linux, MSDN / Windows does not offer it. I could have used `strstr` but then it has a very different prototype and expects only null-terminated strings as arguments. Googling around, I discovered a few implementations of `memmem` but none appeared to truly mimic `memmem`.

I therefore wrote one of my own:

```
void *memmem(const void *haystack_start, size_t haystack_len, const void *needle_start, size_t needle_len)
{

    const unsigned char *haystack = (const unsigned char *) haystack_start;
    const unsigned char *needle = (const unsigned char *) needle_start;
    const unsigned char *h = NULL;
    const unsigned char *n = NULL;
    size_t x = needle_len;

    /* The first occurrence of the empty string is deemed to occur at
    the beginning of the string.  */
    if (needle_len == 0)
        return (void *) haystack_start;

    /* Sanity check, otherwise the loop might search through the whole
        memory.  */
     if (haystack_len < needle_len)
       return NULL;

    for (; *haystack && haystack_len--; haystack++) {

        x = needle_len;
        n = needle;
        h = haystack;

        if (haystack_len < needle_len)
            break;

        if ((*haystack != *needle) || ( *haystack + needle_len != *needle + needle_len))
            continue;

        for (; x ; h++ , n++) {
            x--;

            if (*h != *n) 
                break;

           if (x == 0)
            return (void *)haystack;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

The code does work, but my question is: could it be done more efficiently, or faster?

I hope one of the awesome hacks here will also be kind enough to point out if this implementation has a vulnerability that I may have not noticed.

Comment: Look up the string searching algorithms in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm -- these will get you much better performance than the `Θ(nm)` performance of the naive algorithm you're using.

Comment: Hey @snowbody any implementation of Boyer–Moore string search algorithm in C, that I could use on Windows as well? Please do share.

Comment: I don't understand, the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm page has a C algorithm on it, didn't it work for you? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @snowbody my bad, I didn't notice the c implementation, discussed below the Python implementation. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Ok this has a bug. Fails if needle and haystack are exactly the same. :(

Comment: Modified that code, to fix the bug. Also Incorporated a couple of good tips, by you hacks.

Comment: @heslacher sorry. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: If you want a review of new code, post a new question with the new code and a link to this page. Then post a link to the new one here in the comments.

Answer (score 4):

1. You wrote:

   ```
   for (; *haystack && haystack_len--; haystack++) {

       x = needle_len;
       n = needle;
       h = haystack;

       if (haystack_len < needle_len)
           break;
   ```

   A better way would be:

   ```
   for (; --haystack_len >= needle_len; haystack++) {

       x = needle_len;
       n = needle;
       h = haystack;
   ```

   The `*haystack` is actually a bug as it prevents searching if there are any zero bytes in the range.
2. I think it is a bad idea to have the second clause in:

   ```
   if ((*haystack != *needle) || ( *haystack + needle_len != *needle + needle_len))
   ```

   because you might bust the cache. Keep data access local. Checking the last character is an unnecesary complexity.

Answer (score 3):

**Declare the Variables When They are Needed**
The first five lines of the function `memmem()` are:

```
    const unsigned char *haystack = (const unsigned char *) haystack_start;
    const unsigned char *needle = (const unsigned char *) needle_start;
    const unsigned char *h = NULL;
    const unsigned char *n = NULL;
    size_t x = needle_len;
```

Since x, h and n are loop variants, it would be better to delcare them where their values are assigned:

```
    for (; *haystack && haystack_len--; haystack++) {
        size_t x = needle_len;
        unsigned char *n = needle;
        unsigned char *h = haystack;
```

The pointers n and h are variable, they will change inside the loop, the characters won't change.

The variables haystack and needle start aren't needed utill just before the loop, because they also are only used in the loop..

```
    unsigned char *haystack = (unsigned char *) haystack_start;
    unsigned char *needle = (unsigned char *) needle_start;

    for (; *haystack && haystack_len--; haystack++) {
        size_t x = needle_len;
        unsigned char *n = needle;
        unsigned char *h = haystack;
```

**Simplify the Code**
There is no reason to stay in the function or the outer loop once `haystack_len` is less than `needle_len`.

```
        if (haystack_len < needle_len)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
```

**Make Maintenance Easier**
While the following is perfectly legitimate, it's not the best programming practice, if someone needs to add a second statement to the THEN clause, it might be better to add braces around all THEN and ELSE clauses:

```
    if (haystack_len < needle_len)
        return NULL;
```

would be better as:

```
    if (haystack_len < needle_len)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
```

**One Possible Optimization**
Most computers have a decrement and test opcode, the for loop

```
        for (; x ; h++ , n++) {
            x--;

            if (*h != *n)
                break;

            if (x == 0)
                return (void *)haystack;
        }
```

would probably be faster this way:

```
        for (x = needle_len + 1; --x ; )
        {
            if (*h++ != *n++)
                break;
        }
        if (x == 0)
        {
            return (void *)haystack;
        }
```

The variable x needs to be one greater than the length because --x is tested at the top of the loop.